# Custom View onDraw method not drawing

Tags: android

I'm working on a simple drawing app for a team project at school and the onDraw method, while called reliably, only produces a blank white screen. This happened after we made the decision to switch from using activities to fragments. My Drawing View code worked properly when we were using in a Draw Activity, but now that we're using a DrawFragment, it is not working. I've searched throughout SO looking for anyone that has a similar problem, but to no avail. Originally, I thought this was due to the Canvas parameter passed to the onDraw method having a null bitmap, but when I set the canvas to my own private variable mCanvas, the problem persists.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, when I'm going through the code in my debugger, at the end of the onDraw method, after every line has been called, I can look at the bitmap contained in the canvas and see that is is fully green and has the path that I specified. However, nothing makes it to the actual screen on my device.

EDIT2: Modified my fragment_draw.xml with Mike's suggestion, however I'm still facing the same problem. I tried setting the background of the RelativeLayout to transparent as well to see if that would make a difference and it did not.

My DrawingView:

```
package edu.cascadia.doodlebug;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {

    private final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private float mX, mY; // coordinates for tracking path drawing
    private Bitmap mBitmap; // bitmap for the canvas
    private Canvas mCanvas; // canvas object to draw onto
    private Path mPath; // path for drawing
    private Paint mPaint; // paint to describe the line being drawn
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private Context mContext;

public DrawingView(Context c) {
    this(c, null);
}

public DrawingView(Context c, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(c, attr);
    mContext = c;
    mPath = new Path();

    setWillNotDraw(false);
    setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);

    // set up paint object for the line
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

    // bitmap paint to draw bitmap
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas = mCanvas;
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);

    // Test Code
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(300, 500);
    mPath.quadTo(300, 500, 330, 750);
    mPath.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());
    mPath.close();

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    final float x = event.getX();
    final float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            touchEnd();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {

    // set up the path to start drawing from this location
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);

    // add the start coordinates
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    // get the change in both x and y directions
    float deltaX = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float deltaY = Math.abs(y - mY);

    // check if greater than touch tolerance
    if (deltaX >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || deltaY >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        //draw the line to the new coordinates
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchEnd() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    mPath.close();
    mPath.reset();
}

public int getLineWidth() {
    return (int) mPaint.getStrokeWidth();
}

public void setLineWidth(int width) {
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);
}

public void setBackground(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
}
}
```

My DrawFragment:

```
package edu.cascadia.doodlebug;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class DrawFragment extends Fragment {
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private DrawingView mView;

public DrawFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_draw, container, false);
    mView = (DrawingView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawingView);
    return v;
}

public void setBackground(Bitmap bitmap) { mView.setBackground(bitmap); }

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void startCamera();
}
}
```

EDIT: updated fragment_draw.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="edu.cascadia.doodlebug.DrawFragment"
android:background="#ffff">


<view
    android:id="@+id/drawingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    class="edu.cascadia.doodlebug.DrawingView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/color_selector"
    android:contentDescription=""/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgBee"
        android:src="@drawable/bee_sticker" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgDinosaur"
        android:src="@drawable/dinosaur_sticker" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgKitty"
        android:src="@drawable/kitty_sticker" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgTaz"
        android:src="@drawable/taz_sticker" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgLego"
        android:src="@drawable/lego_sticker" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgTurkey"
        android:src="@drawable/turkey_sticker" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButttonTakePic"
    android:src="@drawable/camera"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The `RelativeLayout` is covering your custom `View`, as you have its width and height set to `match_parent` inside a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I included my custom View inside the RelativeLayout and removed the FrameLayout entirely. However, I'm still facing the same problem. I've updated the xml code, but it seems like it should be working now.

Comment: Remove this line: `canvas = mCanvas;`. Also, `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);` doesn't really do anything as it is; it's just drawing a transparent Bitmap over everything.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I just realized I misread your code, and I misspoke in my last comment. The `canvas.drawBitmap(...)` call, as you had it, was drawing the Bitmap `mBitmap` onto itself, as that is the backing Bitmap for `mCanvas`. You weren't seeing anything because the Bitmap you created is not the on-screen Bitmap the View displays.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too, in my case what I had to do was set the background to something.

```
    <com.microdevrj.hydrogenrecyclerview.HydrogenRV
    android:id="@+id/hydro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

or call

```
setWillNotDraw(false)
```